# How can I give elements in a MongoDB array a key? Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, discord.js

I have an array of elements (which are sub-documents) in a document. Originally this field was just an object which I could use to easily access nested objects like

```
fieldName[objectKey]
```

But this was before realizing you could store schemas inside schemas! Now I have an array of these objects with no way to find one or the other without looping through the entire array and querying each.

[Here's an example MongoDB Compass Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIut3.png)

Originally this object would have been a value to the **guildId** key, which is now a field inside the schema. Ideally if I could take this out of the schema and set it as a key to the object that would be great!

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. You can still query fields even if those are now nested in an array. For example `db.coll.find({"captchas.solved":true})` will return all documents with at least one unsolved captcha.

Comment: @thisDotAdam you might wanna take a look at this article about Data Modeling Patterns from MongoDocs (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to use a map in MongoDb rather than using an array. This will allow me to access an object by its' key!

```
captchas: {
    type: Map, 
    of: captchaSchema.schema
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also another option that will probably help you. You could store this `guild` embedded  docs in another collection. With it's own schema. And store in your original schema only `guild_id` references, like this one:

```
value: "MD17",
captchas: [guild_id1, guild_id2, ..., guild_idN]
```

and then request it by aggregation framework via such query:

```
your_model_name.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    field: value_for_match
                }
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "guilds", 
                    localField: "captchas",
                    foreignField: "_id", //make sure that guild_collection id is safe as reference
                    as: "guilds"
                }
            }
]}
```

And even match the necessary embedded guild doc after `$lookup` stage